# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConfigured' of undefined

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a react native expo project and I want to convert it to react native cli but I am getting error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConfigured' of undefined
This error is located at:
    in DrawerViewBase (created by DrawerView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by DrawerView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by DrawerNavigator)
    in DrawerNavigator (created by MainDrawerNavigator)
    in MainDrawerNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by AppNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNavigator)
    in AppNavigator (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in NSS_GECBSP(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

    error Could not open DrawerView.tsx in the editor.
info When running on Windows, file names are checked against a whitelist to protect against remote code execution attacks. File names may consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods, dashes, at signs, slashes, and underscores.
error Could not open index.ts in the editor.
info When running on Windows, file names are checked against a whitelist to protect against remote code execution attacks. File names may consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods, dashes, at signs, slashes, and underscores.
error Could not open index.ts in the editor.
info When running on Windows, file names are checked against a whitelist to protect against remote code execution attacks. File names may consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods, dashes, at signs, slashes, and underscores.
```

Can anyone help with this. According to chat gpt it is related to navigation but I am unable to resolve this issue please help. If you need any file to go through then ask as I can't post all the files here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it was caused by react-native-reanimated and `plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']` solved my problem, you need to add this inside babel.config.js

**`babel.config.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting same error

Comment: @MuskanVerma Did you solve the issue? Because I am also getting the same issue

Comment: @CoolCoder yes I solved this. I added the plugin in my babel.config.js file -

`module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};`


then I got a error that reanimated version and plugin version are different so I changed the reanimated version from 3.8.0 to 3.8.1 then cleared the cache and also did gradle clean and it started working